# Using a parent vertex property to filter out going vertices

Tags: gremlin

The goal is to calculate the maximum combined `pot` of the graph. The rules are as follows:

Two nodes are compatible if either the `f-mkt` of one node is different from all those of another node `picks` or if they are the same for at least one, then its `pick` should also be the same with that of the other node. For example in the graph below, node 1 has one `f-mkt` of `125*41` which is also found in node 3, however since its pick `123*41*2` is also the same as that in node 3, they are compatible.
However node 2 and node 3 are not compatible because, there is a `f-mkt` of `124*40` in both, but the `pick 123*40*1` in node 2 is not found in node 3, making them incompatible. So the max combined `pot` of the graph is max of(node 1 + node 2, node 1 + node 3), which in this case is 50 + 90 = 130.

In other words, the combined `pot` of the graph is taking the maximum of the sum of `pot` of each node's connected vertices after incompatibilities have been eliminated.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<graphml xmlns='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns'>
    <key id='labelV'   for='node' attr.name='labelV'  attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='type'     for='node' attr.name='type'    attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='picks'    for='node' attr.name='picks'   attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='mkt'      for='node' attr.name='mkt'     attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='f-mkt'   for='node' attr.name='f-mkt'  attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='labelE'   for='edge' attr.name='labelE'  attr.type='string'></key>

    <graph id='routes' edgedefault='directed'>
        <!-- vertices -->
        <node id='1'>
            <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
            <data key='type'>transaction</data>
            <data key='picks'>123*41*2</data>
            <data key='f-mkt'>123*41</data>
            <data key='pot'>50.0</data>
        </node>
        <node id='2'>
            <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
            <data key='type'>transaction</data>
            <data key='picks'>123*40*1</data>
            <data key='f-mkt'>123*40</data>
            <data key='pot'>80.0</data>
        </node>
        <node id='3'>
            <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
            <data key='type'>transaction</data>
            <data key='picks'>125*41*2</data>
            <data key='f-mkt'>125*41</data>
            <data key='pot'>90.0</data>
        </node>
        <node id='4'>
            <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
            <data key='type'>transaction</data>
            <data key='picks'>123*41*1</data>
            <data key='f-mkt'>123*41</data>
            <data key='pot'>40.0</data>
        </node>

        <edge id='33' source='1' target='2'>
            <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='34' source='1' target='3'>
            <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='35' source='2' target='1'>
            <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='36' source='3' target='1'>
            <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
        </edge>

        <edge id='37' source='3' target='4'>
            <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='38' source='4' target='3'>
            <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
        </edge>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

Here's code to complete multi-valued properties

```
g.V(3).property(set,'picks','124*40*3').property(set,'picks','123*40*2')
g.V(3).property(set,'f-mkt','124*40').property(set,'f-mkt','123*40')

g.V(2).property(set, 'picks', '124*40*2')
g.V(2).property(set, 'f-mkt', '124*40')
```

EDIT:
I want to calculate the maximum `pot` for each node in the graph by taking its connected subgraph, and enforcing the rules above in that subgraph before taking the sum of the subgraph's `pot`s, then the maximum of all subgraphs.

To achieve that, I need to have to do comparisons as described above, but I can't even get the below simple test to work:
1
`g.V(1).as('v').map{out().where(values('f-mkt').is(within(it.get().value('f-mkt'))))}`

i get this as response:

`[VertexStep(OUT,vertex), TraversalFilterStep([PropertiesStep([f-mkt],value), IsStep(within([123*41]))])]`

So how do I dynamically pass that value from the parent node to the where step?

Comment: Your question is not clear and very complicated. Are you trying to solve the same question you referenced or a different question? I strongly suggest you create a simplified version of your graph (with clear values like A, B, C and only relevant nodes), or ask specific question. For example, why we should care about rules for compatible, if there is an edge for it already. If your question is about passing value from node A to other node B and compare them, there is no need for your specific graph details.

Comment: I've edited my question. Why we should care about rules is that, V[3] for example is compatible with node 1 and node 4, but when it's connected bulkset, that is itself and the vertices it is connected to are put together, the elements inside this are not all compatible with each other.